# How do you get armor in Halo 5?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

I've been playing Halo 5 for a little bit and I've opened quite a few packs but, I have gotten nothing out of them. Do you only get visors and armor by leveling up?

Answer (score 1):

To quote [this page on the wiki:](https://www.halopedia.org/Armor_permutations_(Halo_5:_Guardians))

> Armor permutations in Halo 5: Guardians allow players to customize their Spartan player model. These armor sets can be obtained by **getting to a certain rank** in the game along with **unlocking achievements in *Halo: The Master Chief Collection*** and **obtaining armor in REQ packs.**

So it sounds like you can get armor in Halo 5: Guardians in those three ways.